# how to return the tag where the click event happened

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to catch the tag where the click event happened, however, I am getting the value not the actual tag. your help will be much appreciated

The tag I am trying to catch `button`

```
<button type="button"  onClick={(e) => handleAction(row, e)}>
  <img src={options} alt="more options" />
</button>
```

passed prop

```
handleAction={this.handleAction}
```

handleAction method

```
 handleAction(row, e) {

    console.log(e.target, row);
  }
```

the output

```
 <img src="/bf8a277f232f78afa8e14c7f6147fc88.png" alt="more options">, myRow
```

Comment: What do you mean by "tag" here? Do you mean the DOM element from the parsed HTML? If so, why do you need the element itself instead of some data about the element? What are you actually trying to accomplish here? Can you describe what you want your user to be able to do?

Comment: What tag are you referring to?

Comment: If I understand your question you can get the tag name of the element that the event occurred on like this: `event.target.tagName`

Comment: I am trying to catch the DOM element `button` because I want to append some other HTML elements using javascript onClick @Code-Apprentice

Comment: What do you mean "catch"?

Comment: "because I want to append some other HTML elements using javascript onClick" This sounds like the wrong way to use ReactJS. Instead, you should set state with some values that reflect what should be drawn on the page. Then in `render()` use the state to draw the correct elements.

Comment: the row is just passed data but they look like this ```{id: 35, name: "arena", address: "burundi, bujumbura", amenities: Array(2), services: Array(2), …}```

Comment: Thanks  bruv @Code-Apprentice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try currentTarget instead of target:

```
console.log(e.currentTarget, row);
```

e.target will return the img tag but e.currenTarget will return the button tag

Answer (score 0):

Below code should suffice the ask:

```
handleAction(row, e) {
    console.log(e.target.parentElement, row);
}
```